# how to display two drop down lists side by side on a button click in java script?

Tags: javascript

Initially after execution there will be two dropdowns along with two buttons.
    If click on the first button again two more dropdowns should appear in the next line side by side.
    But, in my case after clicking on the first button the same dropdowns appearing in different lines.
  The Code is as follows:

```
<head>
</head>
<center>
<table>

    <h2> Choose your Option </h2>
    <hr />
    &nbsp;

    <select id="slct1" name="slct1" onChange="populate('slct1','slct2')">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="P1">P1</option>
        <option value="P2">P2</option>
    </select>
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;

    <select id="slct2" name="slct2"> </select>
    &nbsp;

    <input type="image" name="imgbtn" src="C:\Users\durga.kakaraparthi\Desktop\plus.png" height="15" width="15"
        onclick="myDisplay()">
    &nbsp;

    <input type="image" name="imgbtn" src="C:\Users\durga.kakaraparthi\Desktop\minus.png" height="15" width="15"
        onclick="myHidden()">

    </body>
</table>
</center>
</html>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function populate(s1, s2) {
        var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
        var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
        s2.innerHTML = "";
        if (s1.value == "P1") {
            var optionArray = ["", "P3", "P4", "P5"];
        }
        else if (s1.value == "P2") {
            var optionArray = ["", "P6", "P7", "P8"];
        }
        for (var option in optionArray) {
            var pair = optionArray[option];
            var newOption = document.createElement("option");
            newOption.innerHTML = pair;
            s2.options.add(newOption);
        }

    }


    function myDisplay() {

        document.getElementById('slct1').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('slct2').style.display = "block";

    }
    function myHidden() {

        document.getElementById('slct1').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('slct2').style.display = "none";

    }



</script>
```

Comment: You are following a complete wrong path. Looks like copypasta for me. All you do with `myDisplay()` and `myHidden()` is hiding and showing it onclick. Please take a look at [appendChild()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you. I am very new to JavaScript Could you please explain it more